Function to export csv with PHP: how to get a success message after download
I am developing a wordpress simple plugin. I created an admin page where I show data from a custom MYSQL table created by the plugin.
The download button in this page triggers a download_csv() function written in class_myplugin.php. The download works fine, but I cannot retrieve a success message (which actually contains a script to deselect the checked rows and alerts that data were actually downloaded)
The function to submit data is as follows:
 $('#export_records').on('click', function(e) { 
        var row_data = [];  
        $(".chk_id:checked").each(function() {  
            row_data.push($(this).data('form-id'));
        }); 
        if(row_data.length <=0)  {  
            alert("Please select records.");  
        }  
        else {  
            WRN_PROFILE_DELETE = "Are you sure you want to delete "+(row_data.length>1?"these":"this")+" row?";  
            var confirmed = confirm(WRN_PROFILE_DELETE);  
            if(confirmed == true) {     
            // Create a hidden form and append the selected IDs
            var form = $('<form action="" method="post"></form>');
            form.append('<input type="hidden" name="download_csv" value="1">');
            form.append('<input type="hidden" name="download_csv_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('download_csv_nonce'); ?>">');
            form.append('<input type="hidden" name="selected_ids" value="' + JSON.stringify(row_data) + '">');
            form.appendTo('body').submit();
            }
        }
    });

While in the class file I have :
public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {

        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;
        add_action('admin_menu', array( $this, 'addPluginAdminMenu' ), 9);
        add_action('admin_init', array( $this, 'registerAndBuildFields' )); 
        add_action('admin_notices', array( $this,'sigh_form_tethys_admin_notice'));
        add_action('rest_api_init',array( $this,'sigh_form_handle_delete_entries' ));
        add_action('admin_init', array( $this, 'handle_download_csv' ));
    }
public function handle_download_csv() { 
    if (isset($_POST['download_csv'])) {
        
        if (!isset($_POST['download_csv_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['download_csv_nonce'], 'download_csv_nonce')) {
            print 'Sorry, your nonce did not verify.';
            exit;
        } else {
            
           // Download CSV
            $success = $this->download_csv($_POST['selected_ids']);
            // Prepare message
            $message = $success ? count($_POST['selected_ids']) . ' records were downloaded.' : 'Failed to download records.';
            // Echo message
            echo '<script>';
            echo 'document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {';
            echo 'alert("' . $message . '");'; // Display message
            echo '$(".chk_id:checked").prop("checked", false);'; // Deselect checkboxes
            echo '});';
            echo '</script>';
            
        }

    }
}
public function download_csv($selected_ids) {
        // Set headers for CSV file download
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false);
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"csv_export.csv\";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        // clean output buffer

        // Create a file pointer connected to the output stream
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');   
        // Retrieve data from your specific table
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'sight_form_data'; // Replace 'your_table_name' with the name of your table
        $selected_ids = json_decode($selected_ids);
        $placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($selected_ids), '%d'));
        $request = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id_form IN ($placeholders)", $selected_ids);
            $entries = $wpdb->get_results($request, ARRAY_A);
    
                // Write headers to the CSV file
                $header_row = array(
                    'First name', 'Last name', 'Country', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Date sighting', 'Time sighting',
                    'Species', 'Confidence', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'N animals', 'Offsprings', 'Sea state',
                    'Want to be contacted', 'Privacy consent', 'Video url', 'File URL'
                );
    
            fputcsv($output, $header_row);
    
            // Write data rows to the CSV file
                foreach ($entries as $entry) {
                    // Prepare an array with values to write to CSV
                    $csv_data = array(
                        $entry['first_name'],
                        $entry['last_name'],
                        $entry['country'],
                        $entry['email'],
                        $entry['phone'],
                        $entry['date_sighting'],
                        $entry['time_sighting'],
                        $entry['species'],
                        $entry['confidence'],
                        $entry['latitude'],
                        $entry['longitude'],
                        $entry['n_animals'],
                        $entry['offsprings'],
                        $entry['sea_state'],
                        $entry['contact'],
                        $entry['consent_privacy'],
                        $entry['video_url'],
                        $entry['fileUrl'] // Assuming this is the field with file URLs
                    );
                    fputcsv($output, $csv_data);
                }
            // Close the file pointer
            fclose($output);
        // flush buffer

        // Terminate script execution
        exit();
}

Nothing appears after saving the file and even debugging any step of the code in handle_download_csv() gives nothing.
Could you give me some advice on this issue? Thanks

Are you sure that handle_download_csv is even called? Have you considered sending a request to the WP backend through AJAX? Considering how you're returning JS to the frontend it would be an appropriate solution.

handle_download_csv is called and the file is actually downloaded. Hover since it has an exit at the end, it stops any further if () clause. I tried to add something before closing exit() , which indeed helps, but I don't know how to echo  echo any response back to the same page. I am trying an ajax call but I am having even more problems there. Though I register the action correctly for the admin-ajax.php data are not sent there
